# Algorithm in getting total garnered hours for student

Tags: beginner, php, array, datetime

I'm calculating now the total garnered hours student get in school using php.

(Same concept in getting the total work hours in employee for timesheets)

So I have an array `$attendance` where the student check in and out in school.

```
$attendance = [
  "2019-07-01 08:03:00",
  "2019-07-01 12:12:00",
  "2019-07-01 13:03:00",
  "2019-07-01 17:00:00",
];
```

**$schedules** is on what time the student should check in and out.

```
$schedules = [
  [
    "time_start" => "08:00:00",
    "time_end" => "12:00:00",
    "in_threshold" => 15,
    "out_threshold" => 15
  ],
  [
    "time_start" => "13:00:00",
    "time_end" => "17:00:00",
    "in_threshold" => 15,
    "out_threshold" => 15
  ]
];
```

The **threshold** is a minute the student should check in/out if the student check in above threshold it will result to late. (Eg.  `08:16:00` checks in. He/she is late )

Code below is for storing time_start and time_end to array which is the basis for time_in and out:

```
foreach($schedules as $schedule){

    // Set time_start and time_end with threshold
    $mytime_start[] = date( "H:i:s",
        strtotime('+'. $schedule[ 'in_threshold' ] .' minutes',
            strtotime ( $schedule[ 'time_start' ]
            )));
    $mytime_end[] = date( "H:i:s",
        strtotime('+'. $schedule[ 'out_threshold' ] .' minutes',
            strtotime( $schedule[ 'time_end' ]
            )));
    // Get time_start and time_end to array
    $sched_starts[] = ( $schedule[ 'time_start' ] );
    $sched_ends[] = ( $schedule[ 'time_end' ] );
}
```

Note: The schedule time_start and time_end can be change. Function `getClosestTime` will get the **closest time** of each attendance. It will identify if the logs is for schedule `time_start` or `time_end`.

```
function getClosestTime( $array, $date ){
    foreach( $array as $day ){
        $interval[] = abs(strtotime($date) - strtotime($day));

    }
    asort($interval);
    $closest = key($interval);

    return $array[$closest];
}
```

Get `$attendance` by 2. for Punch IN and OUT

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($attendance); $index += 2)
```

Expected the two element of array is in and out.

```
$date_start = $attendance[$index]; // Punch In
$date_end = $attendance[$index + 1]; // Punch Out
```

Get only date in $attendance (If the schedule cross midnights)

```
$to_date_start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_start));
$to_date_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_end));
```

Get closest Time for each element in `$attendance`

```
$time_start = getClosestTime($mytime_start, date('H:i:s',strtotime($date_start)));
$time_end = getClosestTime($mytime_end, date('H:i:s',strtotime($date_end)));
```

If there's an instance if the student check in late and the closest time is not the exact `time_start` for its `time_end`.

```
if ($time_start > $time_end) {
    $time_start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_start));
}
```

Add dates in schedule time start and time_end

```
$time_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$to_date_start $time_start"));
$time_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$to_date_end $time_end"));
```

Set the exact datetime when the student should check in/out

```
$time_minus_start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-15 minutes $time_start"));
$time_minus_end = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-15 minutes $time_end"));
```

Check `check in` if it is above the threshould same logic for `check out`

```
if ($date_start > $time_start) {
    $start = $late;
    $total_late += 1;

}else {
    $start = $exact_in;
}
```

If `$attendace` is exact time_start and time_end return its date

```
if (isBetween($time_minus_start, $time_start, $date_start)
    && isBetween($time_minus_end, $time_end, $date_end)) {
    $start = $within_in;
    $end = $within_out;

} else if (isBetween($time_minus_start, $time_start, $date_start) && $date_end > $time_end) {
    $start = $within_in;
    $end = $late_out;
}
```

Sum check in and check out result

```
$total_garner_hours += ($end - $start);
```

In my algorithm:

Student **check in early** and **check out late** then `$start`/`$end` return the exact time student should check in/out.

Student **check in late** and **check out early**  `$start`/`$end` return the real-time data.

Here is my live code: https://3v4l.org/9MaEc

I would like to make the code more **efficient** and **reliable**. I'm a beginner and I admit it, my code is so messed up.

Comment: So is this just a repost of the same question after your first post gathered no reviews?  Do you want to delete the first one?  I don't know why CodeReview would want the redundance.

Comment: Its not. Its different.

Comment: Are you not asking for a review of the same script, duplicating lots of the same question body content, and sharing the same 3v4l demo link?  Looks  _rather_ similar at a glance.  Do explain the difference please, because it is not instantly obvious to me.

Comment: A lot of difference but have same function. In previous I only modify the attendance if it is ```early``` or ```out``` but here It calculate the total hours

Comment: It's a continuation of attendance in biometrics in php. Do I need to edit my question?

Comment: That's okay, I just wanted to be clear about the difference.  I intend to review your scripts, but have been too busy at work.  When I find time, I didn't want to do the same review twice.

Comment: If this is a follow on question it is possible to link to the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm does not allow for the possibility of a transition from daylight time to standard time or vice versa.

Without knowing the mechanism for obtaining the date and time, it's impossible to say if the algorithm needs to be aware of time zones. In principle, the student could be attending by video conference and be in a different time zone.

If the time and date is obtained from a device belonging to the student, the student may prefer to operate the device on a time zone different from the school. For example, both the student and the school could be located in New York but the student corresponds with people all over the world, so keeps her laptop set to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Gerard has answered, there are some PHP libraries that deal with time very well which you could implement. One example is [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

I would separate out your date comparisons into its own function. May be useful elsewhere and is a little clearer. Everything in your for loop up to your first if statement could be its own function.

You could improve your formatting a little (don't know if copy and pasting into Stack Exchange has caused it) but you can take a look at [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). Naming variables a little clearer will be helpful to you, those reviewing your code and to anybody who may now/in the future work on this code, e.g. `mytime_start` doesn't make it clear what time you are talking about, and `index` could simply be referred to as the standard `i`.

Remember to [type hint](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/language.oop5.typehinting.php) your parameters and give [return values](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-type-hinting.html).

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Like these? https://3v4l.org/XDTsI